# Regular expression to extract repeat occurrence of a substring

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have input data with one or more repeat occurrence of substring that start with 2 dollar signs `$$` and end with 2 dollar signs `$$`.

For example:

`$$ any_alphanumeric_characters $$ useful_text_1 $$ any_alphanumeric_characters $$ useful_text_2`.

I would like to extract all occurrences of substring `$$ignore_text$$` using regex and replace with blank.

Input

`$$ any_alphanumeric_characters $$ useful_text_1 $$ any_alphanumeric_characters $$ useful_text_2`

Desired output

```
useful_text_1 useful_text_2
```

I am new to regular expression and still exploring on how to use capturing groups in regex. Can one of the experts pls suggest the regex ?

Comment: what language / regex implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
Pattern.compile("\\$\\$\\p{Alnum}+?\\$\\$").matcher(inputString).replaceAll("");
```